# Upgrade to NuGet 3.4.4-rtm-final breaks package restore

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, project.json

I recently updated my version of NuGet to 3.4.4-rtm-final using

```
nuget update -self
```

Now that I've done this, `nuget restore MySolution.sln` fails with the following error:

```
Error reading 'c:\...MySolution\MyProject.NetCore.Tests\project.json' at line 15 column 23 : TODO: unknown keyword platform
  TODO: unknown keyword platform
```

Here's the relevant part of project.json. When I remove the platform specifier, the build fails:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.1"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

What do I need to do in order to fix this?

Comment: VS tells me that I have NuGet 3.5.0. Can you upgrade to that?

Comment: @svick This is the command line version of nuget which I got through `nuget update -Self`. Do you know if there's a way to get the command line 3.5 version?

Comment: Now that I think about it: why are you even calling `nuget restore`? Either use `dotnet restore` or Visual Studio.